# How long will schmaltz last in the freezer?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, freezing, fat

I have three frozen containers of schmaltz. The newest is three months old; the oldest is probably a couple of years old. Are any of them edible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely depends on the kind of schmaltz you are having, but to be honest I never have seen schmaltz gone bad, even after several years. I have had schmaltz in the *fridge* for over a year and it was still perfectly fine.

I'd suggest the following: follow your gut. Just look at it and check for the usual signs. In order: Does it look normal (no mold, no discoloration, normal consistency)? Does it smell normal? Does it taste normal? Then it's probably still good and you can use it for whatever you like. If you're still unsure: use it for cooking only.

Comment: An addendum: The thing that'll happen to any kind of fat in the freezer is that _eventually_ it goes rancid (never happened to me, so I'd guess the timescale required is at least "several years"). A slight rancidness may bring a bit of complexity and actually _improve_ taste, so you may well have a little fatty treasure in your freezer. If it's gone too rancid it smells and tastes bad, but it's still safe to eat (assuming it's not spoiled in any other way). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rancidification

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about the older ones, but frozen schmaltz should be fine for a while, at least a few months.